# I need to match a String in MySql query in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I need to use a query which perfectly works in MySql. and query is

```
SELECT * FROM c2cxdb.jobs where job_title like '%Java%' and job_policy = 'Public' and job_status = 1;
```

where I need to replace java inside %% with a dynamic value that I pass to the method.

```
function AllJobs($job_title){
    $allJobs = DB:: select('select * FROM c2cxdb.jobs where job_title like '%$job_title%' and job_policy = "Public" and job_status = 1');
    dd($allJobs);
}
```

But It shows Division by zero exception when I run it.How to replace the value in my query with the value I Pass.I need to get the $job_title value into query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function AllJobs($job_title){
    $allJobs = DB:: select('select * FROM c2cxdb.jobs where job_title like "%'.$job_title.'%" and job_policy = "Public" and job_status = 1');
    dd($allJobs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function AllJobs($job_title){

    $job_title="%".$job_title."%";
    $allJobs = DB:: select('select * FROM c2cxdb.jobs where job_title like "'.$job_title.'" and job_policy = "Public" and job_status = 1');
    dd($allJobs);
}
```